# How to make phone calls in swift

Tags: swift

First of all I know there are some similar topics as this one but because of my reputation I couldn't comment on those for help and stack overflow warned me not to ask for help from the answers section.. none of the similar posts have answered my question so here I go.

As can be understood from the topic, I want make a phone call on click,
I'm making an app for my business and I want to put in a call button so that people can call me over the app.

here are the attempts I've tried as read from the similar topics:

```
    let phoneNumber = "1234567890"

    if let phoneCallURL = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)") {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL) {
            application.openURL(phoneCallURL)
        }
        else{
            println("failed")
        }
    }
```

so when I run the above code with a phone number it prints out the failed message on the console seems like i fails opening the URL

The other code I've tried is a very similar one

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://phoneNumber")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

one other question is that: What is the correct syntax for the NSURL?

this

```
NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)")
```

or this

```
NSURL(string: "tel//:\(phoneNumber)")
```

My last question is: If the app manages to make a call, does it appear on the simulator like a calling screen? I'm very new to swift programming and I apologise if the questions seem stupid..

Answer (score 4):

The simple format for a `tel:` URL is `tel:######`. `/` is not a number. You probably mean this to be:

```
NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)")
```

assuming `phoneNumber` is a string containing the phone number.

The `tel:` scheme is defined in [RFC2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt). You can look there for details on all its expected features.

Note that phone calls are not possible in the simulator, so you'll receive an error if you try to open a `tel:` URL there (unless you handle the URL yourself by registering an `NSURLProtocol`).

Comment: When I use my code with NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)")
nothing happens, so shall I take this that my code works but not in the simulator?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that; you need to test on a device. But that's the symptom you would probably see (especially since you're not checking whether `openURL` is successful).

Comment: and to test it I have to upload it to the store right? are there any other ways you can legally share here?

Comment: You don't have to upload to the store. Just run it on your device. You can do that from Xcode.

Comment: @RobNapier running an app at device is not allowed, I tried to run it warns me about having a developer account

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return to your app after your call has been ended (which you should do) then you need to use `telprompt://` instead of `tel://`. The `tel://` will take you to the home screen after the call.

Better use this:

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt://1234567891")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let phoneNumber = "0507712323"
if let callNumber = phoneNumber {

let aURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(callNumber)")
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(aURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(aURL)
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
 }
else {
   print("error")}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should expand and describe how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue for different reasons and I would like share with you .

**First**  Dont try in simulator must try on real device

**Second**  make sure the passed number dont contain space

*here is example*

```
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
        // I add this line to make sure passed number wihthout space 
        let CleanphoneNumber = phoneNumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(CleanphoneNumber)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct.It seems that it would always fail if you test it in simulator.
Try to use your iPhone to run it,and it would go to dialer interface as you want.

Answer (score 0):

## i added some additional validation in the code

```
func makeCall(constactNumber : NSString)
{
    if(constactNumber.length == 0)
    {
        print("Contact number in not valid")
    }
    else
    {
        let CleanconstactNumber = constactNumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(CleanconstactNumber)")
        {
            if (UIDevice.currentDevice().model.rangeOfString("iPad") != nil)
            {
                print("Your device doesn't support this feature.")

            } else
            {
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL))
                {
                    let mobileNetworkCode = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.mobileNetworkCode
                    if( mobileNetworkCode == nil)
                    {
                        print(" No sim present Or No cellular coverage or phone is on airplane mode.")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use 'guard' to clean up all these validation 'ifs'.