# Given a phone number, how do I make a phone call in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, function, phone-call

I have a 10 digit phone number held in a string "3133133313" that is downloaded from CloudKit.

I'm looking to use this number to place a call. Therefore, I have the code suggested by Apple.

```
    let call = detail.value(forKey: "Phone") as? String
    let url = URL(string: call!)!
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. What am I missing here that is probably blatantly obvious.

Comment: `"tel:+3133133313"` or `"tel:+" + (call ?? "")`

Comment: I think I love you. I'm surprised Apple TSI support made no mention. But either way, I'm incredibly Leo Dabus! One more question since it just arose. Is there a way to avoid the pop up notifying the user of the call and go straight to the phone app?

Comment: I think the only app you can actually open it is the settings using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: Check out the [Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1) document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make phone calls in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240170/how-to-make-phone-calls-in-swift)

Comment: while incredibly similar, this code includes the completionHandler aspect of updated swift 3 code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Dabus,

I simply had to add the "tel://" aspect to each phone number. In this project, I decided to add this code snippet into my function rather than my CloudKit records.

```
if let call = detail.value(forKey: "Phone") as? String,
    let url = URL(string: "tel://\(call)"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```